# Linker error when creating package for ad hoc distribution

Tags: ios, researchkit

I want to create a version of my app for "ad hoc" distribution. But when I try to compile a version to distribute I get a linker error (I cannot post a screenshot because I need a reputation of at least 10, so I include a Dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ntqs9qaesmz3n9/Schermafdruk%202015-10-04%2017.30.08.png?dl=0 ).

I've read possible solutions on multiple websites (clean project, start project from scratch, etc, etc) but I keep getting the same error. What is puzzling to me is how it can compile and link correctly when I put it directly on my own iPhone, but generates this error when I try to package for distribution?

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Some general info:
Created in Swift with X-code v7 and Researchkit v 1.2

Comment: Instead of posting a link to an image, copy and paste the error message into your question.

Comment: Check if you have added `$(inherited)` to **Other Linker Flags**. From the error it seems ORKLogFormatter class is not  found & being linked for arm64.

Comment: Could you create a minimum stripped down version of your project, still exhibiting the problem, and upload it to GitHub so we can have a look?

Comment: Thanks for the advice - eventually I ended up making a new project and adding the source and data files again. The worked!